# Contact form sending emails but returning error message

Tags: php

I followed the instructions on [this page](https://mdbootstrap.com/components/bootstrap-contact-form/) to setup validation for my contact form. The form sends an email but still returns an "Error!" message. I believe that the problem is with the Mail.PHP file, because the error message is is the one used in the die function

PHP validation

```
<?php
if(isset( $_POST['contact-name']))
  $name = $_POST['contact-name'];
if(isset( $_POST['contact-email']))
  $email = $_POST['contact-email'];
if(isset( $_POST['contact-tel']))
  $tel = $_POST['contact-tel'];
if(isset( $_POST['contact-subject']))
  $subject = $_POST['contact-subject'];
if(isset( $_POST['contact-message']))
  $message = $_POST['contact-message'];
if ($name === ''){
  echo "Name cannot be empty.";
  die();
}
if ($email === ''){
  echo "Email cannot be empty.";
  die();
} else {
  if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    echo "Email format invalid.";
    die();
  }
}
  if ($tel === ''){
  echo "Phone number cannot be empty.";
  die();
}
if ($subject === ''){
  echo "Subject cannot be empty.";
  die();
}
if ($message === ''){
  echo "Message cannot be empty.";
  die();
}

$content="From: $name \n Email: $email \n Phone number:$tel \n Message: $message";
$recipient = 'kimpope1@cox.net';
$header = 'BCC: jonwashdesigns@gmail.com'.PHP_EOL;
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $content, $mailheader, $header) or die("Error!");
echo "Email sent!";
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using

```
mail($recipient, $subject, $content, $mailheader, $header) or die("Error!");
```

use

```
$status = mail($recipient, $subject, $content, $mailheader, $header);
echo $status ? 'Mail sent' : 'Error sending mail';
```

Comment: whats the difference, apart from changing the string? I think the problem lies in the use of parameter 5..

Comment: I was under the impression that using the `or die()`  would not work in every use case - this being one where I suspected it would not

Comment: @LawrenceCherone what is the problem with using parameter 5?

Comment: @JonathanWashington RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php its for parameters to pass to the binary/mta not for BCC headers.

Comment: tbh when I looked at this yesterday I knew there was something odd about the code ~ I should have been more on the ball to spot the 5th element ( as it were )